# VBA operation (save as/open for output as #1) in Sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA script using

> Open *** For Output As #1

```
Sub csv_output()
    Dim irow, i As Integer
    Dim strFile_Path, strFile_Path2 As String
    Dim export_path As String

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
online_path = "https://ABC.sharepoint.com/sites/Shared%20Documents/report.csv"

'edit path
file_Path = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & "\Documents" & "\report.csv"

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Open file_Path For Output As #1

    For irow = 17 To 20

    For i = 1 To 127
        Print #1, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow, i) & ";";
    Next i
   Print #1, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(irow, i + 1)
   Next irow

'try save as to Sharepoint folder
Workbooks("report.csv").SaveAs Filename:=online_path
Close #1
End Sub
```

I expect to have .csv file exporting to Sharepoint folder place. I did try 2 ways but they are all failed:

- way 1: Open For Output As #1 direct in Sharepoint folder (failed: Run-time error '52': Bad file name or number)

  > Open on_path For Output As #1
- way 2: Open For Output As #1 in an offline folder and save as #1 to online_path. I did try these things but all failed:

  > SaveAs #1 Filename:=online_path

  (Compile error: Expected: expression)

  > Workbooks("report.csv").SaveAs Filename:=online_path

  (Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range)

  > Workbooks(#1).SaveAs Filename:=online_path

  (Compile error: Expected: expression)

Looking forward to your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please describe how it fails.

Comment: `SaveAs` Does nothing and is not valid> My comment refers to this *SaveAs #1 Filename:=online_path*

Comment: Anyone plese help, thank you.